# how to open "Add a Google Account" activity using intent?

Tags: java, android

My question is how to open "Add a Google Account" activity using intent without using AccountManager which requires the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
```

I mean find a way to go around the following solution:

```
AccountManager accountMgr = AccountManager.get(context);
accountMgr.addAccount("com.google", "ah", null, new Bundle(), context, null, null);
```

I'll provide the solution for anyone out there searching for the solve this issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

the answer for the above question by providing [EXTRA_ACCOUNT_TYPES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#EXTRA_ACCOUNT_TYPES) in the intent extra data. and set the value to "com.google" in order to alert the activity:

```
public static void startAddGoogleAccountIntent(Context context)
{
    Intent addAccountIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT)
    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    addAccountIntent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_ACCOUNT_TYPES, new String[] {"com.google"});
    context.startActivity(addAccountIntent); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're searching for an adb solution, here it is:

```
adb shell am start -a "android.settings.ADD_ACCOUNT_SETTINGS" --esa "account_types" "com.google"
```