# Using Google OAuth 2 on embedded Android-based device

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

We have an application for embedded Android-based device, it uses WebView and inside it we use Google OAuth 2 to login to the app. Unfortunately [Google will soon block OAuth 2 inside WebView](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/08/23/google_to_block_web_views_from_using_its_oauth/), and we have lots of restrictions:

- The device doesn't have Google Services installed, so probably no ['official' way of logging in](https://developers.google.com/identity/choose-auth) would work (or maybe any of them would work without Google Services?)
- We can't just invoke Android browser to do login, because it shows address bar, which would allow the user to surf the internet, which we can't allow
- We don't fully control the software installed on the device: can't install Google Services, update Android version, install Google Chrome, etc..., we can just update our app.

What else could we do having those restrictions?

Comment: Your app requires users to authorize it to access their own resources? If not, then you probably don't need OAuth. Oauth is NOT authentication

Comment: Unfortunately those are our client's requirements, they have google apps accounts we must use for authentication.

Comment: Be clear, OAuth is not authentication. Google's authentication requires at least a web browser (more for 2FA), there is no way around that.

Comment: Did you try using the oauth flow for TVs and embedded devices? take a look here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices

Answer (score 2):

Implementation through a browser:

1) Register custom URI scheme ([How to implement my very own URI scheme on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-scheme-on-android)), for example, **app-oauth2://**

2) Make access request in user's browser

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
scope=...
access_type=offline&
include_granted_scopes=true&
state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&
redirect_uri=http://example.com/oauth2-handler&
response_type=code&
client_id=...
```

3) If user accept or denied requested rights in the confirmation dialog, it will be redirected to **redirect_uri** (http://example.com/oauth2-handler) with some params

4) On the side of **redirect_uri handler** (http://example.com/oauth2-handler), mare a redirect to custom URI scheme with params:

- *Success:* **app-oauth2://**?state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&code=...&scope=...#
- *Failure:* **app-oauth2://**?error=access_denied&state=state_parameter_passthrough_value#

5) In your app you can parse URI scheme **app-oauth2://** from option 4 and receive the code for future usage or error for displaying to the user.

Comment: Seems like a viable solution. Any thoughts how this might work with Cordova ?

Comment: If Cordova supports custom protocol handling and the possibility of opening the user's browser - yes.

Answer (score 1):

As per the problems on your side it would be best to open an Intent from within the App targeted towards the sign in Weburl [this won't trigger up address bar link]

Refer to this stackOverflow page 
[how to open "Add a Google Account" activity using intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794762/how-to-open-add-a-google-account-activity-using-intent)

now you may use  **Shared preferences**  to store the Authentication data for further logins [ if the requirements of the app permits it.]

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OAuth Web services for implementing a solution based on your needs.

**Reference link**: https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth

Here is a sample github project that is using OAuth 2 web service for logging into Twitter. You can take help from it for consuming the Google's OAuth2 web services in your Android Application.

Repository link: 
https://github.com/sathify/tagpulse

Web service consumption screen link:
https://github.com/sathify/tagpulse/blob/master/android/src/tag/pulse/main.java

I hope this helps.

Comment: this is about oauth 1, google doesn't support it for years

Answer (score 0):

There is a library that supports Android 1.5 and higher for Google OAuth 2:

Sample code found here:

https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/oauth2-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/oauth2/cmdline/OAuth2Sample.java

Comment: this is still browser-based oauth

Comment: Ok what Android API version does the app support ?

Comment: the device doesn't have Google Services installed !! - how do you think this will be done]

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#android it uses AccountManager please read the second link the first seems to point to the OAuth 2 when you have Google Services I've edited the answer

Comment: You are correct @Aloy A Sen so I've edited the answer and in this case you need Google Client API library for OAuth 2 the link is misleading but found the correct code

Comment: this link uses the INTENT https://github.com/sathify/tagpulse/blob/master/android/src/tag/pulse/main.java     this is my answer

Comment: looks like OAuth 1?